# Colab reads a csv file in Google Drive as html

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I have a csv file stored in my Google Drive. When I open it in Colab, it opens like the picture below. Colab seems to think it is a html file. What should I do?
For your reference, I know I can open it with PyDrive, but PyDrive requires authentication each time and so I need another way.

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://drive.google.com/file/d/ 
                 /1c-j4nEO9Pn3E-zf5is5Py3OTG8pXDdrj/view?usp=sharing',
                 encoding='cp949', nrows=100)
```

[image]

Comment: I know it's an old question, but did you ever get a solution to this?